$G=HK$ implies $G = H^xK^y$
"If $H,K \le G$ are subgroups of $G$ and $G=HK$, then $G = H^xK^y$ for all $x,y \in G$."
This is an exercise in Isaacs' Finite Group Theory, Problem 1A4. I was able to prove it under the assumption that $G$ is a finite group, and I am unsure how to show it without this assumption (or if it is even true for infinite groups! Note the title of the book.)
Here is my proof if $G$ is finite: we can reduce the problem to assuming $x=1$ by considering that
$$
G = H^xK^y \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad G = x^{-1}Gx = x^{-1}xH(x^{-1}y)Ky^{-1}x = HK^{x^{-1}y}.
$$
Thus, we assume WLOG that $x=1$.
Now, we use the identity $|HyK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K^y|}$. Since $|G| = |HK|$, we have $|G| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$. Thus, if we can show $|H \cap K| = |H \cap K^y|$, then $|HyK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|} = |G|$ and $|HyK| = |G|$, and since left multiplication preserves order, we have $|HK^y| = |HyKy^{-1}| = |HyK| = |G|$ and we are done.
To show $|H \cap K| = |H \cap K^y|$, write $y = hk$ for $h \in H$, $k \in K$. Then $K^y = hkKk^{-1}h = hKh^{-1}=K^h$, and
$$
|H \cap K^y| = |H \cap K^h| = |(H \cap K)^h| = |H \cap K|.
$$
Therefore, the result holds.

As you remarked we can assume $x=e$. Now if $G=HK$, we write $y=h.k$ (with obvious notations, so that $K^y=h.K.h^{-1}$, and, as $hHh^{-1}=H$, $H.K^y=hHKh^{-1}=hGh^{-1}=G$.

Here is a conceptual way to understand it in the framework of group actions and transport of structure. Arguably it just casts what could be an elementary argument in an unnecessarily advanced viewpoint, but I found it interesting.
First, note that $G=HK$ is equivalent to saying the group action $H\curvearrowright G/K$ (where $H$ acts by left multiplication on left cosets of $K$) is transitive. This is because $HK$ is the union of the $H$-orbit of $eK\in G/K$.
$$ \begin{array}{ccc}
G = HK & & G=H^xK^y \\[3pt]
\Updownarrow & & \Updownarrow \\[3pt]
{H\curvearrowright G/K \\ ~\,\textrm{transitive}} & \,\Leftrightarrow\, & {H^x\curvearrowright G/K^y \\ ~~~\textrm{transitive}}
\end{array} $$
It remains to see how the action $H\curvearrowright G/K$ can be transported to $H^x\curvearrowright G/K^y$. Indeed, we have
$$ \begin{array}{ccc}
H\times G/K & \longrightarrow & G/K \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
H^x\times G/K^y & \longrightarrow & G/K^y
 \end{array} $$
as a commutative diagram: the horizontal maps are the group actions, and the vertical maps are built from the conjugations $H\to H^x:h\mapsto xhx^{-1}$ and $G/K\to G/K^y:L\mapsto xLy^{-1}$. Thus, one action is transitive iff the other is.
Now here is the corresponding elementary train of thought. Rewrite the hypothetical equation $g=(xhx^{-1})(yky^{-1})$ as $x^{-1}gy=h(x^{-1}y)k$. Thus, if we set $x^{-1}y=h_0k_0$ and $x^{-1}gy=h_1k_1$, then we can set $h=h_1h_0^{-1}$ and $k=k_0^{-1}k_1$ to get $g=(xhx^{-1})(yky^{-1})$. This can be done for any $g\in G$.

$G = HK$ implies that $G$ has only one double coset with respect to $H$ and $K$. Hence $G = HgK$ for all $g \in G$. Thus $$H^{x} K^{y} = x^{-1}Hx \ y^{-1}Ky= x^{-1}(Hxy^{-1}K)y = x^{-1}Gy = G$$
